# Save two different desktop layouts on OSX for different environments

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks, workspace

I'm basically in two different modes when I work on my macbook. In one mode, I have a few apps running in desktop 1, another in desktop 2, a few in desktop 3 etc. Then when I switch from work to school mode, I want to run an entirely different layout at the click of a button instead of closing applications, retiling them, making new workspaces, and re-organizing everything.

Anyone know how to accomplish this? Maybe two different user accounts and just log in and out of both? But then it won't 100% preserve the state of everything, like when you close the lid and re-login..

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. For questions about *using* Macs, please visit [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) on the StackExchange network.